# Uncaught ReferenceError When Trying to Use Imported React Selector in React actions file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

**What I want to do:** I want to use a state value in one of my action methods.

**How I would prefer to do it:** Instead of typing out state.sale.oliver.data, I want to obfuscate that by calling my selector, showingTest(state).

**Problem:** Inside my if statement, the value is undefined, and when I use the browser to log the method name. I get an uncaught reference error.

At the top of my actions.js (which is in the same directory as selectors.js)

*actions.js*

```
import { showingTest } from './selectors';
```

In the same file I have a method and inside the method have the following if statement:

```
if (showingTest(state).length >= 3)
```

My code will never go into this if statement,
but if I type

```
if (state.sale.oliver.data.length >= 3)
```

then bingo we are working.

Also for reference we have here my selector:

*selectors.js*

```
export const showingTest = state => {
    return state.sale.oliver.data ? state.sale.oliver.data : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, so here was the issue. I was facing a bug and thinking that my first if statement wasnt working. I was debugging on google chrome and typed that method into the console and there was an uncaught reference error, but when I console.log the value I am indeed accessing the selector.